# How to read values from XML String from Web Service

Tags: c#, xml

my source like this in C#:

```
string xml = null;
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://www.freegeoip.net/xml");
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = res.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();

res.Close();
```

am getting response like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
        <IP>162.158.50.10</IP> //IP address
        <CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>   //Country Code
        <CountryName>India</CountryName>//Country Name
        <RegionCode>MH</RegionCode> //Region Code
        <RegionName>Maharashtra</RegionName>
        <City>Mumbai</City>
        <ZipCode></ZipCode>
        <TimeZone>Asia/Kolkata</TimeZone>
        <Latitude>18.975</Latitude>
        <Longitude>72.8258</Longitude>
        <MetroCode>0</MetroCode>
    </Response>
```

/// XMl Reponse END///////////////////////////////
  I want pass parameters to Database like :

```
 objLogDetails.IPAddress  = ???? //Here i want to pass IP :162.158.50.10 from XMl string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HEre are two methods, one using xpath and the other using linq 2 xml:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace stackexchange
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string theXml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <Response>
        <IP>162.158.50.10</IP> //IP address
        <CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>   //Country Code
        <CountryName>India</CountryName>//Country Name
        <RegionCode>MH</RegionCode> //Region Code
        <RegionName>Maharashtra</RegionName>
        <City>Mumbai</City>
        <ZipCode></ZipCode>
        <TimeZone>Asia/Kolkata</TimeZone>
        <Latitude>18.975</Latitude>
        <Longitude>72.8258</Longitude>
        <MetroCode>0</MetroCode>
    </Response>";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(theXml);
            XmlNode ip = xml.SelectSingleNode("/Response/IP");
            Console.Out.WriteLine($"Ip Address: {ip.InnerText}");

            XElement root = XElement.Parse(theXml);
            XElement address = (from a in root.Descendants() where a.Name == "IP" select a).Single();
            Console.Out.WriteLine($"Ip Address: {address.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using XElement, why not just XPathSelectElement? why go through all the trouble? this dosen't make sense.

Comment: because I had a brain fart, I just woke up and barely sipped my coffee yet, lol

Comment: Error    'string' does not contain a definition for 'SelectSingleNode' and no extension method 'SelectSingleNode' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: i got above error for asp.net (  XmlNode ip = xml.SelectSingleNode("/Response/IP");)

Comment: did you grab the using statements at the top? missing a library in references?

Comment: you need system.xml and system.xml.linq as references

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99191/discussion-between-muthu-and-steve).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here, is use an XElement to get items from the response and insert into your request.

You can do so like this:

```
//sets the node or remove
     public static void SetOrRemoveNodeValue(XElement root, string xPath, string attributeName, string value)
            {
                XElement currentNode = root.XPathSelectElement(xPath);
                if (currentNode != null)
                {
                    if (currentNode.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(att => att.Name.LocalName.Equals(attributeName)) != null)
                    {
                        if (value == string.Empty)
                        {
                            currentNode.Attribute(attributeName).Remove();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentNode.Attribute(attributeName).Value = value;
                        }
                    }
```

then use it like this:

```
 Formatter.SetOrRemoveNodeValue("node", "your value type", "your value");
```

To extract value from the response, simply use:

```
currentNode.XPathSelectElement("//Response").Element("Ip").value;
```

Or simply
`currentNode.XPathSelectElement("//Ip").value;`

Answer (score -2):

Trying This Code ..

```
private string mStrXMLStk = Application.StartupPath + "\\Path.xml";
private System.Xml.XmlDocument mXDoc = new XmlDocument();
mXDoc.Load(mStrXMLStk);
XmlNode XNode = mXDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Response");
if (XNode != null)
{
   if (XNode != null)
   {
       int IntChildCount = XNode.ChildNodes.Count;
       for (int IntI = 1; IntI <= 1; IntI++)
       {
            string LocalName = XNode.ChildNodes[IntI].LocalName;
            XmlNode Node = mXDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Response/" + LocalName);
            string _ip = Node.InnerText;
            MessageBox.Show("IP" + _ip);
       }
   }
}
```

Completely worked

Comment: my scenario not like this .

Comment: On line 4 you could have selected the node you wanted instead of looping: mXdoc.SelectSingleNode("/Response/Ip");

Comment: if they want countrycode or countryname or anything from nodes thats why i used loop otherwise for one node "IP"  Following this mXdoc.SelectSingleNode("/Response/Ip")